# when I modify a file and rebuild on docker the changes are not applied

Tags: docker, nginx, web

i have a problem on docker, i use docker during the developpement of my project to see how it works. But now, when i want to rebuild with my new code, nothing append, it's litteraly the same execution.

here is my dockerFile :

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
COPY . .
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install

RUN ng build --prod
### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and here is the command i use to build and run my container :

```
docker build -t edtmaker .
docker run --name edtmaker -d -p 8888:80 edtmaker
```

Comment: As this is a webapp, try clearing the browser cache or running the app in an incognito window. At a first glance, the configuration and the commands seem fine.

Comment: what the fck i tried so many things and this worked... i'm litteraly depressed

Comment: Browser caching makes developers cry. Happens to all of us.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i receive a comment who just says to clear the cache on the browser, and this worked